# JavaScript if statements combined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I wanted to simplify the following:

```
if ($rootScope.map.visible == 0 && $rootScope.user == $rootScope.mapuser) {
    var owner = "me";
} else if ($rootScope.map.visible == 1) ) {
    var owner = "me";
} else {
    var owner = "you";
}
```

Would this work?

```
if ( ($rootScope.map.visible == 0 && $rootScope.user == $rootScope.mapuser) || ($rootScope.map.visible == 1) ) {
    var owner = "me";
} else {
    var owner = "you";
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? P.S. There is a syntax error in your first example.

Comment: Logically, yes that would work to simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements look equivilant to me. You can prove it using a Karnaugh Map:

```
A = $rootScope.map.visible == 0
B = $rootScope.user == $rootScope.mapuser
C = $rootScope.map.visible == 1
D = A & B
E = D || C

A    B    C    D    E    
=====================
F    F    F    F    F
F    F    T    F    T
F    T    F    F    F
F    T    T    F    T
T    F    F    F    F
T    F    T    F    T
T    T    F    T    T
T    T    T    T    T
```

If E == False then owner = "your"

If E == True then owner = "me"

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and accomplish the same in a single line of code:

```
var owner = $rootScope.map.visible==1 || 
            ($rootScope.map.visible==0 && $rootScope.user==$rootScope.mapuser) ? 
            "me" : "you";
```

Or, if the only possible values of `$rootScope.map.visible` are `0` and `1` (which seems quite likely given the name of the variable):

```
var owner = $rootScope.map.visible || $rootScope.user==$rootScope.mapuser?"me":"you";
```